# How can I install the WolframScripts without root or `sudo`?

Tags: linux, installation

I have tried to install Mathematica 12.1.1 on my Linux system. But the WolframScripts installing asked me that I should install it by root or `sudo`. I cannot get the root account and I want to install it just for my current user. How can I do that?

---

I have installed it with `rpm2cpio`, then I add all the `[path]/bin` paths to the `~/.bashrc` and `source` it. But there is another question that occurred when I run `wolframscript` directly:

```
[quanfeng@XEON ~]$ wolframscript
/home/quanfeng/software/wolfram/bin/WolframKernel: line 15: uname: command not found
Cannot determine operating system.
```

However, if I run `WolframKernel` directly, there is no any question:

```
[quanfeng@XEON bin]$ WolframKernel
Mathematica 12.1.1 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2020 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=
In[1]:= Exit[]
```

So, what does the message `Cannot determine operating system` mean and what should I do?

---

I found that the `wolframscript` cannot find the system command such as `uname` correctly, why and how to fix it?

Comment: IIRC, just tell the install script to use paths in your local tree, then add whatever path used for the binaries to your path list.

Comment: @ciao , hello. I have renewed my question, and can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already solved this problem. The critical point is that the root user has installed the Mathematica 11.2 with its WolframScript and the command `rpm2cpio wolframscript.rpm | cpio -ivdm` will extract the link file `./usr/bin/wolframscript` linking to the file `/opt/.../wolframscript` which is for Mathematica 11.2. Therefore, I run `export PATH=[The path of the binary file named "wolframscript" you have extracted before]:$PATH` and WolframScript runs correctly.